# Hide certain widgets from specific user roles in admin

Tags: plugins, widgets

I'm looking for a way to hide certain widgets from specific user types in the admin, <kbd>Appearance > Widgets</kbd> page?

For instance, admins can see all widgets, but authors can only see a select few?

I noticed there was a Code Canyon plugin, but it requires a framework with it also which I am not using.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with custom widgets, or existing widgets?

Comment: This is with custom widgets only. I have removed all of the default widgets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check for [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) in the action hook `widgets_init` and proceed accordingly.

```
add_action( 'widgets_init',  'remove_widgets_wpse_89138' , 15 );

function remove_widgets_wpse_89138()
{
    // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin
    if( !is_admin() )
        return;

    // Grab current user info
    global $current_user;

    // Check for specific user
    /*
    $username = $current_user->user_login;
    if( 'the_user_login' != $username)
        return;
    */

    // Check for capability
    if( current_user_can( 'add_users' ) )
        return;

    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Pages' );
}
```

Q&A's of interest:

- [Prevent widgets removal](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/53398/12615)
- [Limit number of Widgets in Sidebars](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/19907/12615)

Comment: this works great thanks alot! The only problem I noticed is this also hides the widget from the front-end for that logged in user. Is there a way to hide it in the CMS only?

Comment: @dclawson, `is_admin()` is meant for that, Answer updated.

Comment: Another question/ issue i've found with this. If I have hidden a number of widgets for certain user roles. When they save a widget on the widgets page they hidden ones seem to be removed from the website.

Comment: What if you try to hide a whole widget area?

Answer (score 3):

I actually have a class which i use just for that:

```
/**
* Hide_widgets_role_based
* @author Ohad Raz <admin@bainternet.info>
*/
class Hide_widgets_role_based{
    $has_selector = false;
    $js_selector = '';
    $roles_hide =array();
    /**
     * class constructor
     * @author Ohad Raz <admin@bainternet.info>
     * @param array $args [description]
     */
    function __construct($args = array()){
        if (is_admin())
            add_action('widgets_init', array($this,'hide', 999));
    }

    /**
     * the money function that hides the widgets on the admin side when the user has a specific role
     * @return void
     */
    public function hide(){
        global $pagenow;
        if ($pagenow == 'widgets.php'){
            global $current_user;
            get_currentuserinfo();
            $sperator = "";
            foreach ($this->roles_hide as $role => $widgets) {
                if ($this->has_role($role)){
                    foreach ((array)$widgets as $w_id) {
                        unregister_widget( $w_id );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * add a widget to hide per role
     * @param string $role   role name
     * @param string $widget widget id
     */
    public function addHide($role,$widget){
        if (is_array($widget)){
            $tmp = isset($roles_hide[$role])? $roles_hide[$role]: array();
            $roles_hide[$role] = array_merge($tmp, (array)$widget);
        }else{
            $roles_hide[$role][] = $widget;
        }
    }

    /**
     * has_role check if a user has a role
     * @param  int  $user_id user id
     * @return boolean          
     */
    public function has_role($user_id = null){
        if ( is_numeric( $user_id ) )
            $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
        else
            $user = wp_get_current_user();

        if ( empty( $user ) )
        return false;

        return in_array( $role, (array) $user->roles );
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$widgets_hide = new Hide_widgets_role_based();
$widgets_hide->addHide('contributor',array('WP_Widget_Pages','WP_Widget_Calendar','WP_Widget_Links'));
$widgets_hide->addHide('editor','WP_Widget_Links');
```

Comment: Interesting. In the usage where does `$widgets_hide = new Hide_widgets_role_based();` hook into? Are you suppose to put it all in it's own function and call it a seperate action?

Comment: Also the accepted answer doesn't work because if another user adds a widget to a sidebar that has an unregistered widget in it, it will get removed after the sidebar gets updated. Does your solution fix that?